# Squared Key button for Swift Calulcator?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, calculator, unary-operator

I'm having trouble implementing the squared key function for this Swift calculator.

I am using MVC for this, and the calculation code below are part of a Swift Calculator Brain file separate from the View Controller. The code is attached to a button in the Storyboard.

Could you please advice me on how to use the Swift "pow" mathematic function to square a button and return the result?

Thanks in advance.

```
 private enum Op {
    case Operand(Double) 
    case UnaryOperation(String, Double -> Double) 
    case BinaryOperation(String, (Double, Double) -> Double)  
}


private var operandStack = [Op]()


private var knownOps = [String: Op]() 


override init() { // initialise the known operations

    knownOps["×"] = Op.BinaryOperation("×", *)
    knownOps["÷"] = Op.BinaryOperation("÷") {$1 / $0}
    knownOps["+"] = Op.BinaryOperation("+", +)
    knownOps["−"] = Op.BinaryOperation("−") {$1 - $0}
    knownOps["√"] = Op.UnaryOperation("√", sqrt) 

    knownOps["x²"] = Op.UnaryOperation("x²" pow(2, pow)    //squared key
```

Comment: Why not `{$0 * $0}`?

Comment: Yh that's it! Sometimes I just overlook the most simple solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I see that someone is taking those iTunes Stanford courses ;)

Comment: Yh, they're really useful for my course!